# Guzzle - How to send PUT request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, guzzle

I have two apps, one is an API and the other is going to connect to that api and add, delete, edit items through the api. Right now I'm fine with selecting and inserting, but I'm stuck at updating.

This is how I am trying to do so:

```
public function update($id)
{

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res = $client->put('http://api.dev/api/v1/locations', [
        'auth' =>  ['David', '888177'],
        'body' => ['id' => Input::get('id'),
                    'name' => Input::get('name'),
                    'address' => Input::get('address'),
                    'postal_code' => Input::get('postal_code'),
                    'city' => Input::get('city'),
                    'indication' => Input::get('indication'),
                    'comment' => Input::get('comment')]
    ]);

    return Redirect::route('locations.show', Input::get('id'));
}
```

But I get this eror:

```
GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ClientException

Client error response [url] http://api.dev/api/v1/locations [status code] 405 [reason phrase] explicit_header_response_code
```

If I try this with curl it works fine, so I know that the API side is working correctly:

```
 curl -i -X PUT --user David:888177 -d 'name=testname' http://api.dev/api/v1/locations/137
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My url was in fact wrong, I needed to add the id to the end of it, just like in curl